# how to define integer variable inside make file

Tags: makefile

I am able to define `build=1` as command line argument. For example:

```
make build=1
```

But not able to define`build=1` inside the make file. For example, I have added

```
build=1
ifdef build
echo 'defined'
endif
```

But the `ifdef` part is not executing.

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: It will help us help you if you show us what you have tried. Also, please use the code formatting rather than writing code snippets inline in the text of your question: the {} icon on the visual editor will help you do that.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track and had the assignment to the `build` variable correct. However, you can not just execute a command like `echo` on a random line in a `makefile`. See [3.1 What Makefiles Contain](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Contents.html#Makefile-Contents) to understand what a `makefile` looks like.

The following demonstrates what you could do, for example using the `$(info ...)` function. In this case, `echo` is additionally executed inside a recipe, which is where it is used most of the time.

```
build:=1
ifdef build
$(info build has been defined)
endif

all:
        @echo build has the value $(build)
```

Note the usage of `:=` as opposed to `=`. Although not too important in this example, it is useful to understand the difference. You can find an explanation in the section [6.2 The Two Flavors of Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors).

If you want to learn how to use `make`, keep [that manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) under your pillow. It is complete and readable and contains quite a few examples.

Comment: Thank you for the response Reinier. I have tried by assigning with := as well and it didn't work. control not entering in to ifdef condition. if i change it to ifndef then i see that it is entering. I don't understand what am missing. This code is in build.mk file.